# Is all information of the quantum numbers $m\ell$ lost in a superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, hydrogen, orbitals, spherical-harmonics

I have learned that to create real spherical harmonics, a superposition of degenerate spherical harmonic eigenfunctions can be created using ±*m*l. For example, the *p*x and *p*y (*l* = 1) spherical harmonics are in a superposition of *m*l = ±1. Is it correct to say that all information regarding the quantum number *m*l for the real spherical harmonics is lost, and statements such as 'the real *p*x spherical harmonic corresponds solely to *m*l = +1 and the real *p*y spherical harmonic corresponds solely to *m*l = -1' are incorrect?